# What are the differences between the available rendering engines?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm new to understanding render engines, is there any chance someone could explain a few things about them?

Specifically for Cycles vs Vray:

- Are there any major differences between Blender Cycles and Vray for    function of rendering various things?
- Is there anything the one struggles to do or is completely unable to do while the other can?
- Are the two render engines compatible with one another at all for transferring various assets and setting up scenes? Like object    materials for example, would they have to be recreated in each?
- Are there any advantages to using a purchased third party render engine like Vray over the free Cycles? (Especially if you are a    single user not a studio.)

In General:

- Why are render additional render engines available? Do they offer different functions or unique traits? Why would you want to use a different one?

Comment: I don't think that rewriting it could do something good, so... https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/render-engine-comparison-cycles-vs-giants/ Have in mind that this test is year old, and Cycles is getting better and better.

Comment: I see the one who asked the original question agreed that the new question is an exact duplicate of an older one, but I would note that the older one asks for a comparison of a different pair of render engines (Blender internal contrasted with Cycles), while the new one asks about a different pair (Cycles contrasted with Vray.

Comment: I think native color management config is the big reason why Vray looks so good, Vray kind of brackets or blends multiple exposures, has almost perfect black and white levels, luminance curve and color intensity,  but I'm not 100% sure. Vray is one of the best rendering engines. In my experience if you want Cycles to look more like Vray you'll need to tweak a lot of things,  in compositor and then use an EXR image manipulation software like DarkTable, that way you'll have pretty close results, but even with all of that the results are not the same as good compared to using Vray.